# Determine row number for entry in a sorted SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table storing say student information

`id | first_name | last_name | dob | score`

where `score` is some non-unique numeric assessment of their performance. (the schema isn't really relevant, I'm trying to go as generic as possible)

I'd like to know, for any given student, what their `score`-based overall ranking is. `ROW_NUMBER()` or any equivalent counter method doesn't really work since they're only accounting for returned entries, so if you're only interested in one particular student, it's always going to be `1`.

Counting the number of students with scores greater than the current one won't work either since you can have multiple students with the same score. Would sorting additionally by a secondary field, such as `dob` work, or would it be too slow?

Comment: Do you want to have students with the same `score` value be listed with the same “row number”?

Comment: your databse is small. so that would be a problem to add a comdition, but you can always add a combined index.  but i can't understand what you are searchung for, so please add some data and wanted result

Comment: If you have multiple students with the same score, how do you determine which one gets row number `x` and `x+1` ?

Comment: This seems a bit like an XY problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this row number?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is not quite what you want.  Instead, see `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `JOIN` into a subquery which will provide the ranks of each student across the entire population:

```
SELECT student.*, ranking.rank
FROM student
JOIN (
    SELECT id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) as rank
    FROM student
) ranking ON student.id = ranking.id
```

I suppose the scale of your data will be a key determinant of whether or not this is a realistic solution for your use case.